# Does rake db:schema:dump recreate schema.rb from migrations or the database itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, migration, rake

Does

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

recreate `schema.rb` from migrations or the database itself?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The answer is simple: from the database.

By the way - when you [take a look into the source code of db:* tasks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake) you can see that migration tasks calls schema:dump after the run

```
desc "Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false)."
task :migrate => :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = ENV["VERBOSE"] ? ENV["VERBOSE"] == "true" : true
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate/", ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil)
  Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :ruby
end
```

So the migration works in the way that it change the database and **then** generate schema.rb file.

Comment: I have an existing SQL Server database that I wanted to dump. Doing `rails db:schema:dump:sqlserver` just created a sqlserver_schema.rb file with no tables in it, though.