# Configuring Rails project with mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm learning Ruby on Rails from lynda.com. I just made mysql database and now I'm trying to configure my rails project so it can connect to that database, but no matter what I try, I always hit this error after trying to `rake db:schema:dump`:

```
Kards52Proof$ rake db:schema:dump --trace
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: No database selected: SHOW TABLE
```

I'm at a lost here... why does `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: No database selected: SHOW TABLE` keep occurring?

Comment: What do you have in `config/database.yml` file?

Comment: development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for rake db:schema:dump [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815447/does-rake-dbschemadump-recreate-schema-rb-from-migrations-or-the-database-itse) I'd make the assumption that the database hasn't been created yet. Here's a [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/scaling-ruby-on-rails-setting-up-a-dedicated-mysql-server-part-2) on doing so. Try running it after the setup.