# Rails migration extremely slow even when there are no pending migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, migration, rake

My production rails application takes 167 seconds to run rake db:migrate. 
The sad part is that there are **no migrations to run**. I tried to condition the migration running on checking that there are pending migrations but then the check took just as long.
The only "excuse" in my mind is that the db is not tiny, there are 1M records there, but I see no reason why that would matter at all.
I looked in the log but there is nothing indicating anything going wrong.
I am running with

- Ruby 2.2.0
- Rails 4.2.0

Does anyone have an idea why this is so, and whether there is anything to do about it?

Comment: Does this apply only to migrations or to spinning up your app in general?

Comment: Hi max. Only the migration part

Comment: same, using Rails 5.2.2. still looking for solution. mina deploy --version extremely slow at migration part

Comment: Same problem here (Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.6). Capistrano runs the `rake db:migrate` task and that takes about 2 minutes, even if *there aren't any pending migrations*. The database is very large (100M records). Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Running `rake db:migrate` task also invoke the `db:schema:dump` task, which will update your db/schema.rb.  So even though you have no migrations you are causing other rake tasks to run which could be taking up that time depending on how many migrations/large your database schema is.

You can  look into source code of db:* tasks (.../activerecord/railties/databases.rake)

```
desc "Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false)."
task :migrate => :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = ENV["VERBOSE"] ? ENV["VERBOSE"] == "true" : true
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate/", ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil)
  Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :ruby
end
```

References: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#running-migrations

[Does rake db:schema:dump recreate schema.rb from migrations or the database itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815447/does-rake-dbschemadump-recreate-schema-rb-from-migrations-or-the-database-itse)

Answer (score 0):

The `rake db:migrate` task was extremely slow on a new server, even when there were no pending migrations.

Finally I found that I had a wrong Redis configuration, and the time was actually spent loading the Rails environment (which `rake db:migrate` does) and not running the migrations.

If you have a similar issue I suggest that you run:

```
rails runner "puts 'hello'"
```

If that takes a long time, then the problem is related to the Rails configuration, not something specific to migrations. In that case you can use CTRL-C after some  seconds to kill the process, so that you can see the stack trace and identify where your code hangs.