# How to solve Rails merge conflicts with db/structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, merge-conflict-resolution

I was told that I should follow the below steps if make new migrations in my branch and have merge conflicts with master in the `db/structure.sql` file.

1. In the branch, `bundle exec rake db:drop`
2. In the branch, `bundle exec rake db:create`
3. In master, `bundle exec rake db:structure:load`
4. In the branch, `git merge master`
5. In the branch, `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

What are steps 1-3 necessary if all I want to do is align the `db/structure.sql` file? By merging in master, don't I get the new migrations I haven't ran yet and then by running them, it will update my `db/structure.sql`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, dropping and recreating the database to solve a conflict in `db/structure.sql` (or `db/schema.rb` for that matter) is a little ridiculous. You should be able to simply run the new migrations and get an updated `structure.sql` from the `db:migrate`.

---

The `db/stucture.sql` file is simply the database's structure as the database sees it (whereas `db/schema.rb` is the database's structure in the limited view of it that ActiveRecord has). If there is a conflict in `structure.sql`, that simply means:

1. The merge involves new migrations which change the database structure.
2. The branch you're merging in has run the migrations in a different order so the schema's don't quite match up even though they may be functionally equivalent.

**(1)** is solved by running the new migrations and possibly fixing any places where the migrations themselves are in conflict. A quick `bin/rake db:migrate` should fix this and leave you with a new non-conflicted `db/structure.sql`.

**(2)** is solved the same way. You could also do a a manual `bin/rake db:structure:dump` to rebuild `db/structure.sql` but you'd only do this if you're certain that you really do have this situation; but really, `db:migrate` will take care of it so there's no reason not to just `db:migrate`.

Conflicts in `db/structure.sql` (or `db/schema.rb`) don't indicate a problem with the `db/structure.sql` itself, they indicate problems with the database that **git** can't directly see. The solution to the conflicts is to fix the database.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get why you would have situation 1 though, wouldn't it always be a result of situation 2 if you have a conflict? In situation 1, the HEAD's `structure.sql` will have more stuff in it (in the correct order) than then branch's `structure.sql` that is being merged in, so there wouldn't be a conflict right?

Comment: AFAIK, if two branches are modifying the same table or if migrations are run, undone, and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `bundle exec rake db:structure:dump` to re-generate the db/structure.sql file.

For schema.rb I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/3815807/6003161